# Can't run tests that interact with the desktop

Tags: coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, microsoft-test-manager, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have downloaded and installed in a windows server 2016 a vs test agent, which was installed by a tool called `Test Agent Configuration Tool`. I then followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ee291332(v=vs.110)) to configure the agent to run tests that interact with desktop - I want to run CodedUI Tests for web projects from whithin my release pipeline.

This is the output from the Test Agent Configuration Tool
[image]

When I run my release pipeline I get this error during the test phase:

> Error calling Initialization method for test class
>   Captura.PDV.Web.Test.CodedUI.CodedUITest1:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To
>   run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test
>   agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How
>   to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the
>   Desktop" (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012)
>
> If you are
>   running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the
>   build agent to run as an interactive process. For more information,
>   see "How to: Configure and Run Scheduled Tests After Building Your
>   Application" (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254735)

Here is my test task configuration:

[image]

Some notes and questions:

- I can run the tests calling `vstest.console.exe` manually from within the server with success
- My release pipeline runs on VSTS
- I am not using Microsoft Test Manager - Is it really necessary?
- Do I need to set up a test lab enviroment?
- Do I need to have a controller for the agent?

I just want to run my tests in first place to see how it goes and then proceed to more advanced tests scenarios using MTM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixed up between the old way of doing things and the new way.

- You don't need to use MTM -- MTM is deprecated.
- You don't need to set up a lab environment. Lab environments are deprecated.
- You don't need special test controllers or agents.

All you should need to do in order to run UI tests is:

1. Set up a build/release agent that runs [interactively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#account).
2. Run the tests on that agent with the Visual Studio Test task with the "Test Mix Contains UI tests" check box checked.

That's it.

I'd also recommend **against** using Coded UI and instead use Selenium (or Appium for desktop applications); Microsoft is no longer investing in the Coded UI platform and recommends using Selenium as an alternative.

Comment: I downloaded an agent from `https://{your_organization}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool` installed it on my machine (tried both starting a session for the agent at the login time and also running it manually with `.\run.cmd`)and I got the same error telling me that the agent must be in interactive mode. After configuring the task to run with "test mix contains ui tests" I am also getting this: `2018-07-26T20:06:15.4361906Z ##[error]Unhandled: Unexpected end of JSON input
2018-07-26T20:06:15.4372741Z ##[error]Unhandled: Command failed: cscript.exe //Nologo C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\_tasks\VS..`

Comment: "Microsoft is no longer investing in the Coded UI" any sources for that? I need to justify it here at my company, this would be helpful

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/visual-studio-team-services-testing-tools-roadmap/

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti, The choice between Coded UI and Selenium is not as clear cut as Daniel's words above suggest. I recommend careful reading of the Microsoft blog to see how your needs may be affected.

Comment: @AdrianHHH could you point out those articles from Microsoft blog? Any recomendations? From the blog post that Daniel sent, I clearly see the advantage of switching from Coded UI to Selenium or any other tool more compatible with WebDrive technology. I am starting to implement functional tests now on my solution, so this would be a good time to switch if needed. Would you recommend me to stay with Coded UI knowing that? If so why?

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti I do not understand what you are asking. I thought the Microsoft blog was clear and I recommended that you read it carefully. What other articles are you referring to?